# Was Pakistan's supreme court in a position to prevent military generals from taking oaths as presidents?

Tags: military, pakistan

According to Wikipedia, Gen. Zia-ul-Haq and Gen. Pervez Musharraf appointed themselves as martial law administrators in the late 1970s and late 1990s respectively, and then, after one or two years, they took oaths as presidents.

<sub>- ***Martial law*** is the imposition of direct military control of normal civil functions or suspension of civil law by a government.</sub>

<sub>- ***Martial Law Administrator*** is a senior and authoritative post that gives the post holder considerable executive authority and powers to enforce martial law in the country. This office has been used chiefly by military officers staging a coup d'état.</sub>

In the case of Zia, he appointed his favorite chief justice, and in the case of Musharraf, he amended the constitution.

Reading the Wikipedia links ([Zia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Zia-ul-Haq#Appointment_of_martial_law_administrators) and [Musharraf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pervez_Musharraf#Constitutional_changes)), it is not clear to me how much resistance they had to face from the SC except for [refusing to take the oaths and resign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_Pakistan#Provisional_Constitutional_Order_and_Supreme_Court) or was the SC in a position to do anything else. It is also unclear whether SC could even do anything against the army's brute force.

My question is, was Pakistan's supreme court, theoretically or practically, capable of preventing Gen. Zia and Gen. Musharraf from taking oaths as presidents?

Why or why not?

Comment: I don't think that this question can be answered based upon legal authority. Politics.SE or History.SE might be a better place to pose the question.